# How do I do '--all' the default for git-fetch?

Tags: git, version-control

When I run git-fetch I would like it to default to the '--all' mode. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose an alias could do the trick:

```
$ git config alias.fa 'fetch --all'
$ git fa                            # fetches all remotes
```

I didn't see in [`git fetch` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-fetch) and [`git config` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-config) a way to force the `--all` option by default.

Comment: Note: I prefer *not overriding* fetch itself by an alias of the same name, to avoid unexpected surprises.

Comment: Actually you can't (from another question about shadowing git commands through alias). It is possible to set it up as a bash alias of the same name though, which I confused with git alias

Comment: This is what I've done in the interim although I wish there was some config for this. I haven't been able to find it yet.